# "Abend in target program" as a general exeption when traying to execute web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl, mainframe

I just have a web service that communicate with a **mainframe**, i don't manage the mainframe just the **.Net** part.

Everything was working fine until last week. i just start getting this error when the service call the Input function on the service

Messege:

> "Abend in target program"

Source:

> `System.Web.Services`

Stacktrace:

```
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at ws.UIBP0012Service.UIBP0012Operation(ProgramInterface UIBP0012Operation1)
   at CW.BusinessLayer_C.boServiceIVRTwo.Traer_Perfil_IVRTwo()
```

Please Help, if you need any other info please comment

Comment: Abend is the abnormal end in an mainframe program so this is probably just a problem in the mainframe program behind the web service.

PS: You should remove project specific information from your post, for example, where are the class files in your machine in the stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the abnormal end (abend) occurred in the target program, it's probable your SOAP request was well-formed and conforms to the WSDL to some extent.  If this is a CICS web service you're communicating with, it may be that validation is turned off (it usually is in a production environment per IBM recommendation) so you may have passed data the target program regards as invalid in your request.  It's also possible there's a bug in the target program.

In any case, you likely want to talk to the person responsible for the target program and the two of you can collaborate on a solution.